# -webkit-backface-visibility causes memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a jQuery plugin and found some strange issues with:
`-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` property.

My goal is to clone HTML elements and then delete them completely from HTML.

If I have `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` on those elements, Chrome still keeps some nodes in memory (inspect elements>timeline>record memory>see nodes).

[Jsfiddle without backface property demo (works fine)](http://jsfiddle.net/Owl/Gp4jb/) **vs**
[Jsfiddle with backface property demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Owl/RVEm3/)

Regarding Demos: Click on Clone button to duplicate first five elements and then use Remove button to remove clones from scene.

Thanks

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I don't see any sort of _memory leaks_ Both were same. And how do you know if it is memory leak ?

Comment: Check Chrome  (inspect elements>timeline>record memory>see nodes).

Comment: My question is how can i avoid memory leaks with using -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden on elements.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. You can maybe avoid memory leaks by reporting the bug?

Comment: I wasnt sure is this a bug but later i reported this in Chrome. I havent tested this on other browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small bug in Chrome. Until a bug fix comes out, I would suggest using a different browser. I have tested it in Safari and it works fine. Good luck!